# yii: login with frameset

Tags: yii

I have a frameset in yii application like this:

```
|     main menu     |
|-------------------|
|         |         |
|content1 | content2|
|         |         |
|-------------------|
|      footer       |
```

Now I have a login page at 'content1' and want to refresh all frames after login.

If I add

```
<form ... onsubmit="document.parent.refresh()">
```

into login form, it's refreshed before it's logged in. There must be better way to do that?

Comment: If you add what? Are all the frames on the same domain?

Comment: sorry, the HTML code was hidden in my question. All the frames are in the same domain.

Answer (score 0):

Your almost there with the document.parent.refresh() just in the wrong place. The onsumbit event is fired when the form is submitted **before** the page and thus login happens. What you need to do is refresh the parent frame after the login.

Add the following code to your login action of the controller:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('reloadParent', 'document.parent.refresh();', CClientScript::POS_LOAD);
```

All this does is add the 'document.parent.refresh()' to the html of the page.